# Has an injured Flash ever used super-speed to walk on his hands?

Tags: dc, the-flash, dc-animated-universe

While watching [flashpoint-paradox](/questions/tagged/flashpoint-paradox) the Flash—in the typical way speedsters are often rendered nigh-useless—suffers a leg injury, therefore preventing him from running. However, a bum leg doesn't mean the Speed Force abandons him: Flash, apparently can still do super-speed *everything else* (which is a lot) *except* run. Hence this question.

Has the Flash been shown, after suffering a leg injury and during a mission, using super-speed to move from place to place by a means *other* than running? For example, I know that, visually, it'd be ridiculous to have the Flash move at super-speed while doing a [handstand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handstand) wearing a cast on his leg or whatever, but that might be exactly such an event's appeal to, for example, a Golden or Silver Age writer.

I am less interested in, for example, the Flash using a (probably, given the rigors of super-speed, tricked-out comic book-style version of a) wheelchair or roller skates and moving at super-speed—while that's in the same wheelhouse, I'm more concerned about the Flash's seeming vulnerability during combat scenarios and how it seems writers believe the Flash largely immobilized if some villain gets lucky and breaks his shin.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no due to the fact he heals super fast.

Comment: @Durakken I've thought that the Flash's fast healing capabilities were a more recent addition to his power set, but an answer saying *No because* then showing the Flash healing fast enough a serious leg injury sustained during combat so that he starts running again during the *same* combat would be fine.

Comment: I haven't read much of flash so i don't know for certain so I'd rather not answe conclusively and rather let someone who has read a significant chunk say so ^.^ I just know he has Super healing. The best i can offer is there might be a scene with Impulse/Kid Flash doing it in one of the Teen Titan/Young Justice books

Comment: People who walk on their hands still need healthy legs in order to maintain their balance.  Even if the Flash had previously trained himself to walk on his hands, no doubt by way of a condensed gym session facilitated by his super-speed, if his legs were still disabled all their flopping around would likely make hand-walking impossible.

Comment: @HeyICanChan In the specific example you mention, he heals enough to run again just a few minutes later. However, his opponent continued to attack, preventing him from recovering until the fight is over.

Comment: @jpmc26 It was the *until the fight is over* part that inspired this question: Flash is sprawled there, Reverse Flash looming over him and mocking Flash's leg wound, and I'm all, "Dude, seriously, you have super-speed *hands*! Use them!"

Comment: @HeyICanChan I know. I just wanted to mention it as a side note. I'm not convinced Flash had the chance to use an alternative strategy, though, given the nature of his opponent and how constant the attacks were. He was getting pummeled pretty badly.

Comment: @DougWarren Being off balance just results in being pulled downward by gravity. That happens pretty slowly compared to how fast the Flash would be moving. Don't think that would actually be a concern.

Comment: Relevant but not an answer: Check out the latest issue of Dark Knight III: Master Race. Flash has his legs broken so Bruce hooks him up to a super computer system to predict weather. He is seen using his speed to do a ton of calculations really quickly at the keyboard.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

In [*The Flash* (v1) #146](http://www.comics.org/issue/18532/) (1964), the story "The Mirror Master's Master Stroke" (auth: John Broome, art: Carmine Infantino and Joe Giella) has the titular villain switch legs with the Flash (yes, switch legs) and our hero is forced to run on his hands instead so that he can defeat him. Not quite the same as having an injury to his legs, but close enough, if you ask me.

Here's a key panel from that story:

[image: Flash Fact! This is incredibly goofy. But pretty awesome.]

Comment: I know that comments saying +1 are generally frowned upon, but, man, this is absolutely perfect *and* hilarious. Thank you so much for hunting this down. I knew it had to be old school if it ever happened. (Seriously, *switches legs?* Awesome.)

Comment: Gotta love that Editor's note. There weren't enough! exclamation points!

Comment: Personally, I think having your legs removed counts as an injury.

Answer (score 52):

Yes, in *Flash* (vol. 1) #190, published Aug. 1969, the Flash suffers a broken leg:

[image]

Within the story Barry Allen goes to a rather elaborate, Silver Agey ruse to prevent people from learning that he is temporarily incapacitated, involving a spare Flash costume that he sews shut, fills with "energized gas" and controls with transistors that -- oh, never mind.  But in order to stay in proximity with his Flash RealDoll he uses a wheelchair at super speed; he also vibrates to remain invisible:

[image]

**Addendum:**  Nowhere in the story is there any reference made to Flash having any kind of accelerated healing; I am not sure when that power became canon, but apparently it was not yet so at this point.  However, at the end of the story there is a final scene that hints at this.  Note that the explanation given here is not that he heals super fast, but rather that the same vibrations that he used to become invisible have some kind of therapeutic effect on his broken bones:
[image]

Comment: Do you know who is the artist of the cover?

Comment: @camden_kid No idea, I don't see an artist's signature on the cover.  It reminds me of some early Bronze Age *Sgt. Rock* covers, so maybe Joe Kubert?  That's just a guess, though.

Comment: Definitely Joe Kubert. It's clearly his style and the GCD confirms it. http://www.comics.org/issue/22880/

Answer (score 24):

There was also a silver age Justice League story where the villain (Brain Storm, a personal favorite) gave physical handicaps to the heroes - Superman was blinded, Green Arrow lost his arms, and the Flash's legs were merged into a single leg.  They of course learned how to triumph over their disabilities and defeat the foe.  The Flash did it by super-speed-hopping.

[image]

Comment: As amusing as this is, he is still technically using his legs.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish However, I *do* think having one's legs fused together counts as an injury *and* super-speed hopping counts as *not running*, so it's cool. Further, it seems this injury happens then is overcome *in combat* so his injury doesn't make him all *O nos! No fightan for me! Goin out for ice creams!* or whatever. (Note that what I really appreciate about this is the heroes explaining their disabilities, especially Hawkman, who considers himself disabled because *he can't fly.* Wait here, Hawk-dude—I'll be right back with my violin.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a person whose leg is injured in the real world. Can he walk on his hands? Similarly, Flash can only do at super speed what he can normally do at "regular" speed. Thus, he would not be able to do gymnastics or "walk" on his hands at super speed if he has not trained himself to do so at "human" speed.

Note that things such as dodging bullets, running up walls, etc. are based on normal movements speeded up. Note that people have "run up walls" in real life because of the movement. Dodging bullets is like dodging a ball thrown slowly..

Comment: So the Flash is doing everything that your or I *could* just *faster*? I guess, in the broadest sense, that works, but it seems to starkly limit the Flash's powers and doesn't seem to entirely jibe with many depictions. (That is, *dodging* is something anyone can do, but *dodging bullets* isn't, and *running* is something anyone can do, but *running on water* isn't.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Dodging bullets is something a normal person could do if they were doper fast. Walking on your hands is not something a normal person could do no matter how fast they are.

Comment: Yo, being "doper fast" would be the shiznitz.

Comment: I want to upvote this last comment so badly.

Comment: People can walk on their hands, and with extreme reflexes and relatively strong athleticism I believe flash would be able to learn to do so easily.

Comment: What about vibrating to increase temperature (how he's dealt with being frozen in ice a few times IIRC, including in a race against Superman)? I mean, there's shivering that normal people do, but in that case it's the muscle exertion that generates the heat, not really the movement.

Comment: @Bellerephon What about running up walls or through time?  How about the tornadoes he makes from circling his arms or throwing lightning?  The idea of Flash just being a normal person moving super fast eventually breaks down.

Comment: @DavidStarkey I haven't seen the tv series or read the comics so I can't explain those. I was just trying to explain the answerer's point.

Comment: @Bellerephon I would say walking on hands should be much easier for the flast because the ratio of your reflex vs the effects of gravity is significantly in your favor.  The problem with a normal person walking on hands is that you are not used to balancing on it, but if it is slowed down, then you shouldn't have problems.  It's sort of like balancing on your hands while you're in a pool, sort of... (yes, there's buoyancy, but there's no good examples here really.)

Comment: If you can dodge a ball you can dodge a wrench... er... bullet.

Comment: @Nelson if you try to do push-ups while upside down against a wall, you will quickly see that it takes a good amount of arm strength. An untrained adult couldn't do it, especially with a broken leg. If he had practices beforehand then he could.

Comment: Well, I've got two daughters who can both hand-walk at a pretty good clip. (Gymnasts...what can I say?). I expect that if push came to shove The Flash could manage to learn a skill that eight year old girls can handle. :-)

Comment: So Flash can heal his injured leg faster than a normal human?

Comment: I think it's pretty meaningless to answer a question of "has any comic book author written a story with this plot point" with "that would be quite unlikely in the real world". You could apply this to all sorts of questions, e.g. "Has any comic book character died and come back to life?" "I don't believe in reincarnation". Comics don't, in general, adhere to such neat logic.